# Boot error: Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

Tags: boot, grub2, lenovo, boot-repair

I've got a Lenovo Thinkpad X220 running Ubuntu 22.04, and it's recently stopped booting successfully. (FWIW, it's an old laptop I gave to my son as hand-me-down, and yesterday he dropped it. So that could be part of the problem.) On startup, it gives me the following error message:

> Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi - Device Error
> Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi: Device Error
> start_image() returned Device Error

I was able to successfully boot from a boot-repair USB, and got the output at the following pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qpQnmZsz8k/

The only thing that seemed like an obvious red-flag (to my non-expert eyes) was that "No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda". I tried a to use boot-repair to repair the filesystem, but this got me the same result in the end.

When I ran `sudo fdisk -l`, the output for sda (my Linux filesystem) included "The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used."

I tried to address the missing bootloader problem by reinstalling GRUB using the instructions [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/grub-efi-reinstall), but when I came to the critical step (running `grub-install`) I got a bunch of error messages reading:

> error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.

It just sort of churns along, repeating that error message over and over. After a few minutes, I got the following:

> grub-install: warning: File system `fat' doesn't support embedding.
> grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible. GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists. However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
> grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.

I'm officially out of my depth here. Any ideas on how to proceed?

**UPDATE:**
Following the suggestion below from ubfan1, I booted in UEFI rather than Legacy BIOS, and ran `boot-repair` again. It didn't seem to do much, but I did get a [pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hwD6TJngfM/) that shows some weird stuff (an unknown bootloader beginning at line 186; a bunch of I/O errors beginning at line 221).

I ran `dosfsck` (from the terminal on the boot-repair live USB), and it spotted unreadable clusters in a bunch of important-looking files (grubx64.efi, shinx64.efi, mmx64.efi), and claims to have repaired 308 files and 2808/130811 clusters.

Now, when I boot up (without the live USB), instead of ending on an error message I just get a black screen. I'm going to try `boot-repair` again to see whether anything changed.

**UPDATE 2:**

I'm starting to think I should just reformat the HD and reinstall Ubuntu. Before I do that, it would be nice to be able to back up some files that are in `/dev/sda2`. I can't figure out how to mount it, though -- when I open it up in `Disks`, there's no little "play" button to mount the way there is for the first partition of my HD (which only contains EFI and BOOT). Is it possible to mount this partition and salvage the data on it?

Comment: At the black screen, try to start a virtual terminal with the key combination ctrl + alt + F4 and see if you get a login prompt.  May be a video problem if that works.  Try a hashcheck on the grubx64.efi file and compare it to the one from the install media (under EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi).  dosfsck may not have totally fixed things.

Comment: I used `sha256sum` to compare `/media/lubuntu/2A9E-3436/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` (from my hard drive) to `/cdrom/EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi` (from the live USB). They definitely don't match. I'm not sure if they _should_ match, given that one is Ubuntu and the other is (apparently) Lubuntu. The virtual terminal also didn't work.

Comment: You can add replies to your original posting, comments may be deleted in the future.  Consider refomatting the EFI and doing a fresh grub-install (or let boot repair do it).  If the format has IO problems, new disk time (but maybe a temp fix would be to make another EFI partition in another location).

Comment: In disks, select the disk, then select the partition to mount, and under the partition display, there is a "play" triangle to mount the selected partition, and a gear icon to change the mount options (if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

No problem that a legacy bootloader is "missing" from your MBR, your install is in UEFI mode.

In your UEFI settings (formerly known as BIOS), set the UEFI boot as preferred over legacy. You machine is UEFI, but the boot-repair is booting in legacy (because both legacy and UEFI boots are present).  Then redo the boot-repair and see if a repair is offered.  The only thing I see that might cause a problem is that EFI/Boot/grubx64.efi is not present.  The new shim will use the grubx64.efi in EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi, but older ones did not, they only read from their own directory.

Try dosfsck on the EFI partition.  It might find any obvious problems.

Comment: Thanks... I think I'm making progress, but not quite there yet. I added an update above with a new pastebin.